# Need D3 Map file uStates.js

Tags: svg, d3.js

I am attempting to recreate the map example found here: http://bl.ocks.org/NPashaP/a74faf20b492ad377312

I am unable to find the file it uses called uStates.js

Could someone point me in the right direction?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using F12 in any browser then go to the network section and refresh the page. Then all you need to do is copy the address:

http://bl.ocks.org/NPashaP/raw/a74faf20b492ad377312/3513ad985b2fa93ea35f2fc864cb30540c298171/uStates.js

Answer (score 3):

I turned on network tracing on Firefox and that suggested that [this is what you want](http://bl.ocks.org/NPashaP/raw/a74faf20b492ad377312/3513ad985b2fa93ea35f2fc864cb30540c298171/uStates.js)